# How to make divs not move during zooming in grid layout

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gridview, zooming

I have the problem during zooming in browser. I split "details__view" to two grid columns but during zooming these columns do not keep their position and width. I tried to use position: absolute, and position:relative but then the division into columns completely disappears. Here is my html:

```
<div className="box__details">
          <div className="details__container">
            <div className="details__container--title">Details</div>
            <div className="details__view">
              <div className="label">Name</div>
              <div className="value">XYZ</div>
            </div>
            <div className="details__view">
              <div className="label">Second Name</div>
              <div className="value">XYZ</div>
            </div>
            <div className="details__view">
              <div className="label">Country</div>
              <div className="value">XYZ</div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.box__details {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 30px;

}

.details__container {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.details__container--title {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.details__view {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: .4fr .4fr;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.label {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.value {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Do you have any ideas how can I make labels and values ​​do not change during zooming? Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

The columns do not keep their position because you're using `fr`. This makes the box stay in the place you put it in on the screens proportion thus moving the right a little left when zooming in (Kinda like using `%`). To make it stay in place you may have to use something like px;
By changing `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` to something like `grid-template-columns: 427px 427px;`